# How I can SAP B1 to integrate to visual studio 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, integration, sapb1

I installed visual studio 2008.

After I  installed SAP B 1, but I do not integrate to visual studio 2008. How ı can integrate SAP B 1 in visual studio 2008 ?

How I can SAP B1 AddOnInstaller.Net Wizard add to on Visual Studio 2008 like below picture ?

[image]

I want to be to open visual studio 2008 like above  picture. But My visual Studio 2008 opening like bottom image. Can you help to me please ?

why My visual studio 2008 do not opening like above picture ?

I want to add my visual studio 2008 to SAP B1 AddOnInstaller.Net Wizard. How I can do it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from my short experience with SAP you have 2 ways (which I'm using):

1. use SQLCLIENT (**TO READ**). connect directly to your company database using sql connection.
2. use DI API to (**read and write**). you can find all the information about it in your SDK help file.

    for **VB B1 addon wizard to Visual studio**: 
   I didn't use it before but I found this link , i think it's similar to your problem
   [B1 AddOn wizard](https://scn.sap.com/thread/1018149)

   PS. I find this page is good for SAP users/developers [scn.sap.com](https://scn.sap.com/welcome)

    hope it helps

   Regards,
   Samira

Comment: Hi Samira, thanks for your answer. I did explanation with picture about my problem . How do i will solving  my problem  ? what you think about my problems ?